# Runtime-dynamic properties in QPropertyEditor

Tags: c++, qt, propertygrid, propertyeditor

I am using the QPropertyEditor from Qt-Apps.org.

is it possible to create a class with exposed Properties where the amount of properties is runtime-dynamic? So for example you have a class which represents a vector of floats with an arbitrary length which is not known at compile time. So you have a

```
vector<float> myFloats;
```

as a class member. How to expose this as a property with the Q_PROPERTY macro. So at the end I like to have the following view in the property editor widget:

- MyClass

  - value of myFloats[0]
  - value of myFloats[1]
  - value of myFloats[2]
    ...
    ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [dynamic properties](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qobject.html#setProperty)  ...

In your class u can set at runtime the dynamic properties of that class

```
DynamicPropertiesClassForQPropertyEditor()
{
    QVector<int> properties;
    ///.... fill in thevalues
    for (int i=0 ; i!=properties.size() ; ++i )
    {
        const QString propertyName = QString( "value of properties[%1]").arg(i);
        setProperty( qPrintable(propertyName) ,properties.at(i) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Next question ;) -->
Is it possible to call a function when a dynamic property was edited in the PropertyEditor? Because my class is only a wrapper for another class so I have to make sure that the other class is updated when some property is changed in the ProperyEditor.

Comment: a QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent is sent to the object